# New relic keeps logging 'Starting Agent shutdown' is this normal or misconfigured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

Ruby on Rails hosted on heroku using newrelic_rpm (3.6.2.96)

I'm seeing many occurrences of `INFO : Starting Agent shutdown from our workers.`
Is this normal? or is it an indication that it's misconfigured?

Comment: Did you find a way to turn off this message?

Comment: No not without forking the gem. I still think that @dirty_joker's answer is the wrong way round. Switching to debug to see if it was a failure, I guess he's not a developer.

Answer (score 2):

That line in the logs is pretty standard behavior. If you turn up your log level to debug you can see if it was an actual failure or if it terminated "gracefully".

After an agent sends data to New Relic's collector and has no further input, it typically shuts down.

Comment: I believe that you have it the wrong way round. If there is a failure then it should be logged at error or warn, and I then turn logging to debug to determine the cause. If on the other hand the agent  terminated gracefully then I don't need to be informed.

Answer (score 1):

In your app, in *config\new_relic.yml* you will find a line like this

```
log_level: info
```

in either the *common:* section or the section for your environment (on Heroku this will be the *production:* section)

To turn off the annoying message, change the line to read

```
log_level: error
```

and push the app to Heroku.

Comment: Yes that will turn off this annoying message but also turn off all other info messages. The issue is that to see if there was indeed a failure I am advised to turn log level to debug.

Comment: I found this page when I was trying to turn off the message you originally asked about. The reply by dirty_joker didn't explain how to change the log_level so my reply is here as a reminder for me and assistance anyone else who's having the same problem as me. It may not be the correct answer for your problem.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded gruff, your comment is valid, and will be of help to others.